# Typesetting a context-free grammar

Tags: pdftex, syntax

Is there a latex package that can be used to produce a language grammar similar to the following figure? If yes, which package?

[image: sample grammar]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apparently LaTeX is used for the output of the image, so either it was directly used or a special package seems to exist ;-)

Comment: Exacty! Therefore, I'd like to know which package?